# How can I see an image located in /data/data/com.mypackagename/files/Documents in android

Tags: android, adb

Is the a way to see a image /data/data/com.mypackagename/files/Documents on android device

I tried copying it to sdcard but got a permission denied error. Its  a debug build.

Comment: With a debug build you can launch the adb shell, then type `run-as your.package.name` and get a new shell as the application.  If you have external storage permission as that app you can then do the copy (or cat with a redirect), otherwise you may need to chmod 0644 the file and then adb pull it by full path name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the file to have a .debug. in its name and then send yourself the debug snapshot and you will get the file in the debug snapshot